# Poster image is not working in videos, with version 1.5.0 update of azure media player

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, azure-media-services

I am facing a weird problem, after upgrading my azure media player to version 1.5.0 it is not taking up the poster image, in version 1.3.0 it is working absolutely fine.

Here is the code I am using.

```
<div class="marginBlock" id="mediaPlayer">
<h3>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"><%=Title.ToString()%></asp:Label>
</h3>
<video id="<%=mediaPlayerID %>" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered">
</video>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"><%=Description.ToString()%></asp:Label>
</p>
```

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    var playOptions = {
        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        autoplay: false,
        controls: true,
        heuristicProfile: "High Quality",
        techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "html5", "flashSS", "silverlightSS"],
        logo: { enabled: false },
        poster: "<%=ImageSelector%>",
        width: '100%'
    };

    var azurePlayer = amp('<%=mediaPlayerID%>', playOptions);

    azurePlayer.src([{
        src: "<%=VideoURL%>",
        type: 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml'
    }]);
</script>
```

Where mediaplayerID, VideoURL, Title, Description and ImageSelector are dynamic values coming from backend and this code is working perfectly with version 1.3.0 of azure.

Comment: Is the poster a relative or absolute URL?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media Player 1.5.0 had some security enhancements, one of which was requiring the poster to be an absolute URL.  Switch to use the absolute URL and it should work fine.  We will update the documentation to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks I will work on it, we are using a CMS so we need to work on it to add a logic to use absolute URL.